# Javascript/jquery filter results based on multiple selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, selection

I'm trying to find a solution for a problem where I need to refine the result based on multiple criteria.
I have multiple selection criteria:

1. Fruits - apple orange grape
2. Vegetables  - tomato potato broccoli
3. Nuts -  walnut peanut almond
4. Cereal - corn wheat rice
5. Spices - cinnamon ginger pepper

User can select only one criteria from every group, for example you can select apples, but not oranges or grapes. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uncite/LSMxC/29/).

Then I have multiple baskets with different items in it.

```
 <div class="results">
      <div class="basket" data-keywords="apple broccoli peanut rice cinnamon">Result1</div>
      <div class="basket" data-keywords="apple tomato almond wheat pepper">Result2</div>
      <div class="basket" data-keywords="orange potato peanut rice ginger">Result3</div>
      <div class="basket" data-keywords="apple potato walnut corn ginger">Result4</div>
      <div class="basket" data-keywords="grape broccoli peanut corn ginger">Result5</div>
</div>
```

But the problem is that these results must to be refined based on multiple criteria. For example, I have selected apples and then tomato, so I need to refine the results, that that user can see only the results with apple and tomato.

Here is my the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uncite/LSMxC/29/). At the moment results are filtered only based on one criteria (keyword), but I need somehow to include other.

Comment: Please clarify and be more precise. I've looked at your jsFiddle and it seems to work on multiple criteria? when I choose Apple and pepper it only shows Result2. This seems correct, no?

Comment: I changed a little bit the results, so you can see, that it doesn't work on different criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your whole javascript/Jquery script with the below mentioned script and check the changes with ur requirements

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.sortLink1').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault(event);
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        var SelectedAry = $(".selected");
        var flag = false;
        if(SelectedAry != undefined && SelectedAry.length == 0)
            flag = true
        sortResult(flag);
    }
    else{
        $('a.sortLink1').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        var SelectedAry = $(".selected");

        var flag = false;
                    if(SelectedAry != undefined && SelectedAry.length == 0)
            flag = true
        sortResult(flag);

    }}
       );
    $('a.sortLink2').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault(event);
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        var SelectedAry = $(".selected");
       var flag = false;
                   if(SelectedAry != undefined && SelectedAry.length == 0)
            flag = true
        sortResult(flag);
    }
    else{
        $('a.sortLink2').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        var SelectedAry = $(".selected");
        var flag = false;
                   if(SelectedAry != undefined && SelectedAry.length == 0)
            flag = true
        sortResult(flag);

    }}
       );

    $('a.sortLink3').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault(event);
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        var SelectedAry = $(".selected");
        var flag = false;
                    if(SelectedAry != undefined && SelectedAry.length == 0)
            flag = true
        sortResult(flag);
    }
    else{
        $('a.sortLink3').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
       var flag = false;
                    if(SelectedAry != undefined && SelectedAry.length == 0)
            flag = true
        sortResult(flag);

    }}
       );

    $('a.sortLink4').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault(event);
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        var SelectedAry = $(".selected");
     var flag = false;
                   if(SelectedAry != undefined && SelectedAry.length == 0)
            flag = true
        sortResult(flag);
    }
    else{
        $('a.sortLink4').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        var SelectedAry = $(".selected");
      var flag = false;
                    if(SelectedAry != undefined && SelectedAry.length == 0)
            flag = true
        sortResult(flag);

    }}
       );
    $('a.sortLink5').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault(event);
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        var SelectedAry = $(".selected");
        var flag = false;
        if(SelectedAry != undefined && SelectedAry.length == 0)
            flag = true
        sortResult(flag);
    }
    else{
        $('a.sortLink5').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        var SelectedAry = $(".selected");
       var flag = false;
                   if(SelectedAry != undefined && SelectedAry.length == 0)
            flag = true
        sortResult(flag);

    }}
       );

$('.basket').addClass('showMe');
positionThumbnails();

    });


        function sortResult (flag){

                $('.results .basket').each(function(){
                var thumbnailKeywords = $(this).attr('data-keywords');
                if(flag){
                $(this).addClass('showMe').removeClass('hideMe');
                }else{
                    var  mymatch = false;
                    var SelectedAry = $(".selected");
                    SelectedAry.each(function(){
                    var newKeyword = $(this).attr("data-keyword");

                    var test_regexp = new RegExp("\\b"+newKeyword+"\\b");
                    mymatch = thumbnailKeywords.match(test_regexp);
                        if(!mymatch)
                            return false;
                    });

                    if(mymatch){
                    $(this).addClass('showMe').removeClass('hideMe');
                    }else{
                    $(this).addClass('hideMe').removeClass('showMe');
                    }
                }
                });
                positionThumbnails();
            }

    function positionThumbnails(){
    $('.basket.hideMe').animate({opacity:0},500,function(){
    $(this).css({'display':'none'});
});
$('.basket.showMe').each(function(index){
    $(this).css('display','block').animate({opacity:1},500)
});
```

}

Please check your requirements and compare your scripts too. for the knowledge 
jsfiddle please visit "http://jsfiddle.net/LSMxC/32/". Please check at your end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively short js script to parse the html for matches:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sorting > div a").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }

        $('.results .basket').each(function(){
            var basketKeywords = $(this).attr('data-keywords');
            var match = true;
            $(".sorting > div a.selected").each(function(){
                if (!basketKeywords.match($(this).attr('data-keyword'))){
                    match = false;
                }
            });

            if (match){
                $(this).addClass('showMe').removeClass('hideMe');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('hideMe').removeClass('showMe');
            }
        });

        positionThumbnails();
    });
});

function positionThumbnails(){
    $('.basket.hideMe').animate({opacity:0},500,function(){
        $(this).css({'display':'none'});
    });
    $('.basket.showMe').each(function(index){
        $(this).css('display','block').animate({opacity:1},500)
    });
}
```

Comment: It works, but I need somehow to add class showMe to all results at the begging.